# React function with fetched data- show n/a if empty : show fetched data

Tags: reactjs

Hi I'm trying to create a condition in reactJS that if fetched data is empty then it should show "n/a" otherwise show fetched data. How to do that ? I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

```
const x =(text)

const myFunction = () => {
(x === null)? "n/a" : x}
```

//fetched component with data//

```
  <FetchedComponent>
 {text}
 </FetchedComponent>
```

Comment: you need to use useState and render html based on that. Share more code will help to understand your issue

Comment: @KavithaKT is this what I have. I did not create use state for that actually. Also data is fetched from backend so I used as props. Everything is working how it should but I just need to create a function that if fetched data is empty then must show text N/a othervise show fetched data.

Answer (score 0):

```
return ({text !== null && <p>
 {text}
 </p>}
{text === null && <h3>n/a</h3>)
```

We dont need function.Try like this.

Comment: I have tried that ..Unfortunately doesnt work ..;/

Comment: Can you share code on which this function exist. <FetchedComponent>
 n/a
 </FetchedComponent> is this what you required? when data not available. Updated my answer

Comment: I have tried also this:      const [text, setText] = useState(fetched.text)

        const myFunction = () => {
       let data = (text.length < 0) ? "n/a" : text;
       setText(data)}

Comment: yes, in my <FetchedComponent > i have to show logic.

Comment: Hi. Its kinda working with this logic: const [text, setText] = useState(`${fetched.data}`);   and then in <myFetchedComponent> I have added the logic {text === null ? <h4>n/a</h4> : text}  but I dont know what to do with SetText ??

Comment: Seems like you don't need useState,  {fetched.data=== null ? <h4>n/a</h4> : fetched.data} is enough

Comment: hahha yes! we have complicated too much :D Its working , thankyou :)

Comment: Happy to know that issue is resolved